# How to install and debug older Qt versions in newer Qt and QtCreator?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmake

When I updated from Qt 5.6 to 5.12, I had to revert one of the projects that I was working to Qt 5.6, and turned out that the two Qt installations where messing with each other. Unfortunately, Qt 5.12 installer does not provide an option to install 5.6 anymore.

So I decided to move the Qt 5.6 SDK to inside the Qt folder with the 5.12 installation. After setting up QtCreator to use both versions, everything worked fine, except I could not debug the 5.6 version anymore. It gave me an error in the path to Qt 5.6 lib folder (it was pointing to the old directory) when linking, and another one in the debug log:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in ""
```

After searching for all files in qt installation folder using the old path, I replaced all occurrences with the new path but the issue persisted. It was when I realized that the previous path was also hardcoded in some binary files that qt uses like QtCore_debug. I searched on the internet for ways to regenerate these files but I could not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending many hours trying to find a workaround, what solved the issue was:

1. Rename the current Qt installation folder (with Qt 5.12 inside) to something else (e.g. from ~/Qt to ~/Qt_);
2. Install the 5.6 version (I got it from [here](http://download.qt.io/new_archive/qt/5.6/5.6.3/)) to the same directory where 5.12 was installed (in my case ~/Qt). During the installation process I noticed the moment where Qt installer run the scripts to generate the binary versions with hardcoded paths, which this time are now correct;
3. Copy the Qt 5.6 SDK to the Qt 5.12 install location (e.g. copy ~/Qt/5.6.3 to ~/Qt_/). Both qt versions should be now inside this folder;
4. Delete the previous Qt folder;
5. Rename it back to the original name (e.g. from ~/Qt_ to ~/Qt).

When done, just open QtCreator, add the new Qt SDK (e.g. 5.6) and created a new Kit with it.

You are done. Have fun!

Comment: Wow. Still true in Qt 6.2.2. Qt's documentation on adding kits/versions frustratingly omits the install step and it's far from obvious. The `qt-unified-macOS-x64-4.2.0-online` installer makes it hard, but check "Archive" to find older versions. Then, as stated, just install (another 5GB) to a new directory and add the SDK + Kit. Copying the SDK folder not useful beyond tidying up. Just point Qt Creator to `qmake` in the older version.